# Bash : Checking if a archive root is folder or it contains files

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to make common extract function for all archives:
But before extraction i want to check: Whether the root of archive is a folder or file. If root of  a archive if folder and it does not contain file then extract it as it is. But if root of archice  is a file or if its contain both file and folder then make new folder same as archive name and then extract archive into that folder

Checking Method should work with all major archives
*.tar.bz2 *.tar.gz *.bz2 *.rar *.gz *.tar *.tbz2 *.tgz *.zip *.Z *.7z * *.tar

For tar based archives i am using

```
ex() {
if [[ -z "$(tar -ztf "$1" | sed '/\//d')" ]]; then tar -zxvf "$1"; else tar -zxvf "$1" -C DIR; fi
}
```

Comment: What if it's both?  What if the `tar` file contains both files and folders at the root level?  What if it's only directories, but there are multiple directories? What if some or all of those directory names already exist in the location where you are extracting to?

Answer (score 0):

I have a `unz` zsh script for that:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
tmp=$(TMPDIR=. mktemp -d -- ${${argv[-1]:t:r}%.tar}.XXXXXX) || exit
print -ru2 Extracting $argv[-1] in $tmp
cd -- $tmp || exit
[[ $argv[-1] = /* ]] || argv[-1]=../$argv[-1]
(PS4='Running '; set -x; "$@"); ret=$?
files=(*(NDY2))
case $#files in
  (0) print -u2 No file created
      rmdir -v "../$tmp";;
  (1) print -u2 Only one file/dir extracted at the top level.
      mv -v -- $files .. && rmdir -v ../$tmp;;
  (*) print -u2 More that one file/dir extracted at the top level.
      mv -vT ../$tmp ../$tmp:r;;
esac && exit $ret
```

To be used as:

```
unz tar xf file.tgz
```

```
unz unzip file.zip
```

etc.

The idea being to extract the archive in a temporary directory, which is only kept if more than one file is extracted at the top level.

(assumes GNU `mv`/`rmdir`)